# Angular2: Rendering the same component with different ids

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a common top-bar with few buttons on it. Buttons route to the same component `dashboard` with different parameter. I want to read that parameter and make changes to the dashboard. 

On Dashboard I am just updating the source url of the iframe based on the parameter passed from the top-bar buttons.

Once dashboard component loads first time, constructor(), ngOnit or ngOnChange do not get called when the buttons get clicked from the top-bar.
Here is the code:
**app.component.html**

```
    <button md-button  [routerLink]="['/dashboard', 'first']"  id="first" class="top-link">First</button>
    <button md-button  [routerLink]="['/dashboard', 'second']" id="second" class="top-link">second</button>
    <button md-button  [routerLink]="['/dashboard', 'third']" id="third" class="top-link">third</button>
```

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.dashboardId = route.snapshot.params['id'];
    console.log("Constructor "+route.snapshot.params['id']);
    this.dashboardUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.first_url);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("OnInit "+this.route.snapshot.params['id']);
    //this.dashboardUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.first_url);
  }
```

How can I pass the button id from top bar to dashboard component and refresh the page?

Comment: The constructor is called when its loaded for the first time but not when you click on the 'dashboard/:id' route from the dashboard right ?

Comment: **constructor(), ngOnit or ngOnChange do not get called when the buttons get clicked from the top-bar** by this what do you mean?

Comment: @YounesM I got that part. Then which lifecycle method get called? Is there another way to pass button id from app.component.html to dashboard.component?

Comment: @Aravind Yes. That is what I mean.

Comment: Does it make sense do not get called when get clicked.

Comment: You could use `ngDoCheck()`, `ngAfterViewChecked()` or `ngAfterContentChecked()` but it seems that they're called each time a component is updated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a normal behavior.
You can subscribe to route change and update the component accordingly:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.changeMeOnUpdate();
}

changeMeOnUpdate(){
    this.sub = this.activatedRoute
        .params
        .subscribe(params => {
            //do what you want with your params and update the component
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What is `this.sub` here? I am new to RxJS.

Comment: It's [rxjs Subscription](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscription.js~Subscription.html) `import { Subscription }   from 'rxjs/Subscription';` You can use its reference to unsubscribe when the component is destroyed to prevent memory leak `this.sub.unsubscribe();`.

Comment: very strange... if you can provide a plunker reproducing your issue, I'll take a look.